# Water leakage into the basement

Tags: water

I found water is leaking into the basement from the wall close to the driveway. See attached pics.

I went to Home depot and asked for some kind of sealant until I do the waterproofing after the winter. They recommended me to fill the gaps with **SAKRETE** brand **Instant Water plug**.
See attached pics

Experts in water leakage repairs, please suggest if above one is the correct one or should go for something else.

Thanks in advance!

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any brand of hydraulic cement should work if you follow the directions.  It is not as simple as just slapping it on/in a gap, it takes a little prep work for it to seal well.

Comment: Can Sand Mix an option too? https://www.homedepot.ca/product/sakrete-sand-mix-30-kg-topping-and-bedding-mix-of-portland-cement-concrete-applications-and-repairs/1000109081

Comment: Hydraulic cement tends to expand a bit when drying, making a tighter seal.  Why it is used for water leaks/wet work.  Most other cement types will just sit there or shrink a bit, and cannot be used in running water.

Comment: Your answer is very useful. Thank you so much crip659.

Answer (score 1):

For the areas with broken up asphalt concrete, hydraulic cement will work, but it probably won't look as good as a hot patch. [This product](https://www.homedepot.com/p/MAXphalt-1-Gal-Plus-Hot-Mix-Asphalt-Patch-X9021/204076804) seems novel (and I'm a sucker for novelty), although I don't think I like the idea of its smell in my food after abusing the microwave like that. For the edges where your hydraulic cement cold joins with other materials, I would use some kind of elastomeric sealant. Realistically, plugging those broken up areas is probably enough, but sealant between foundation and slab might have prevented the broken up asphalt concrete in the first place.

Comment: Kinda cool.  So you have to spend $50 each on a tamper and a used microwave.  It's a reasonable expense to make a DIY project achievable, even if you throw them out after. 
 Like buying a special drill bit or whatever you need to get a project done.

Comment: @jay613, or even an old chunk of 4×4 and a framing hammer could work. I'll be looking for any excuse to use that crazy product now that I know it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Your root problem is two-fold, 1. The aging asphalt has settled and separated from the walls, and 2. The settlement has caused a reverse slope that diverts rainwater towards the house rather than the yard/away from the house. Hydraulic cement won't do the job for either.

For a quick short-term solution, I suggest inserting a backing rod or a stripe of fillet insert into the gap, leaving a little gap on top, and then sealing the gap with flexible tar.

For the long-term solution, you need to reverse the outdoor slope to allow for free draining away from the house.

Comment: I poured Bituminus in the gaps and then applied SAKRETE brand Cold Patch all along the wall with bit of slope towards the driveway. So far I don't see any new leakage but should know how is it helping especially after a heavy rainfall or water seepage after snow melting. Currently monitoring.
Thanks everyone for your comments and suggestions. Really appreciate for everyone's inputs!